# ALTER TABLE lhm migration deletes existing values

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, migration, alter-table

```
require 'lhm'

class RenameField1ToField2ForTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Lhm.change_table :table do |m|
      m.ddl("ALTER TABLE %s CHANGE COLUMN field1 field2 FLOAT DEFAULT NULL AFTER field3" m.name)
    end
  end

  def down
    Lhm.change_table :table do |m|
      m.ddl("ALTER TABLE %s CHANGE COLUMN field2 field1 FLOAT DEFAULT NULL AFTER field3" m.name)
    end
  end
end
```

What happend:

1. Rails-4.0: rake db:migrate
2. Field was renamed successfully.
3. All existing field values are erased, why? Any ideas?

Edit:

- old datatype was `float(11)`
- MYSQL 5.6

Comment: What was the previous data type?

Comment: Old Datatype was float(11)

Comment: I can't reproduce, doesn't look like it's coming from MySQL. I don't know ruby so I am stopping there. SQLfiddle if anyone want to play with it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/096a5/1

Comment: MySQL version 5.6. Fiddle looks good, working like our migration. So its no mysql problem okay :/

Answer (score 4):

I would highly suggest you utilize the methods made available to you from LHM that mimic the ones from Rails (if you plan to use LHM):

```
Lhm.change_table(:users) do |m|
  m.change_column(:old_column, :float)
  m.rename_column(:old_column, :new_column)
end
```

If you look at the method definitions, you will see LHM is doing a `MODIFY` where you are doing a `CHANGE` for `change_column`, and a `CHANGE` for `rename_column`.

Official Docs:

change_column:
https://docs.omniref.com/ruby/gems/lhm/2.2.0/symbols/Lhm::Migrator/change_column?d=415590290&n=0#

rename_column: https://docs.omniref.com/github/soundcloud/lhm/2.2.0/symbols/Lhm::Migrator/rename_column?d=409846811&n=4#

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a straight rails migration like so:

```
def change
  rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
end
```

I've never used lhm so this might not be possible?

Also you might not need the "FLOAT DEFAULT NULL" in your current SQL statement if it's already specified in the DB.

Hope that helps.

Comment: With the lhm migration i cant go the normal rails way, sadly. And since the migration is already run through i just want to get the reason why the values where erased

Answer (score 0):

rename 1st_name to temporary_name, and then rename 2nd_name to 1st_name, and then rename from temporary_name to 2nd_name